# Why cant my PHP-FPM find libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.2.1?

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, fpm

I have a Docker container built from the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/php.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log
networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my php/Docker file:

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

# Install prerequisites required for tools and extensions installed later on.
RUN apk add --update bash gnupg less libpng-dev libzip-dev nano nodejs npm openssl su-exec unzip curl nginx supervisor

# Install yarn as global npm package.
RUN npm install -g yarn

# Install prerequisites for the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv PHP extensions.
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/8/868e5fc4-7bfe-494d-8f9d-115cbcdb52ae/msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.apk \
    && curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/8/868e5fc4-7bfe-494d-8f9d-115cbcdb52ae/mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk \
    && curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/8/868e5fc4-7bfe-494d-8f9d-115cbcdb52ae/msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.sig \
    && curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/8/868e5fc4-7bfe-494d-8f9d-115cbcdb52ae/mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.sig \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import - \
    && gpg --verify msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.apk \
    && gpg --verify mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk \
    && apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.apk mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk \
    && rm *.apk *.sig

# Retrieve the script used to install PHP extensions from the source container.
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/install-php-extensions

# Install required PHP extensions and all their prerequisites available via apt.
RUN chmod uga+x /usr/bin/install-php-extensions \
    && sync \
    && install-php-extensions bcmath ds exif gd intl opcache pcntl pcov pdo_sqlsrv redis sqlsrv zip

# Downloading composer and marking it as executable.
RUN curl -o /usr/local/bin/composer https://getcomposer.org/composer-stable.phar \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

# Setting the work directory.
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Here is my PHP code:

```php
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo "ID: " . $row['id'] . "<br>";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

When I run `docker-compose up` everything starts as expected.  However, when I try to run a simple query to SQL Server, I get this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[01000]: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.2.1' : file not found

I've confirmed that the file is there:

```bash
81f9341151fb:/# ls -hald /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.2.1
-rwxr-xr-x    1 1001     1001        2.0M Oct 26  2022 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.1.so.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the specified architecture of `msodbcsql` and `mssql-tolls` packages.  I'm running this on an M1 MacBook Pro.  I needed to find the `arm64` packages.  Here's the updated part of the Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/msodbcsql18_18.3.2.1-1_arm64.apk \
    && curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_arm64.apk \
    && curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/msodbcsql18_18.3.2.1-1_arm64.sig \
    && curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_arm64.sig \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import - \
    && gpg --verify msodbcsql18_18.3.2.1-1_arm64.sig msodbcsql18_18.3.2.1-1_arm64.apk \
    && gpg --verify mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_arm64.sig mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_arm64.apk \
    && apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql18_18.3.2.1-1_arm64.apk mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_arm64.apk \
    && rm *.apk *.sig
```